# How to resolve git conflicts after taking pull request in Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, git-merge-conflict

I am using Visual Studio and recently I have taken pull request from master and now it's saying me "There are unresolved conflicts in your directory" error while committing my changes.

Can someone please help me to resolve git conflicts after taking pull request in Visual Studio?

Comment: Find the files that it thinks are conflicted. These will have `<<<` markers in them and won't compile. (Even if they're not compiled e.g. CSS, HTML, JS then VS should show you a warning in the IDE.) Work out what the code should be and fix them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stage the file that had the merge conflict, then you can commit the merge.

For more help you can refer https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/merge-conflicts